# restlet item group cusstom price

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create an SO using restlet in Netsuite. The question that I have is when the item is an itemgroup, how do i pass the json so that the restlet can customize the price level etc for children elements of the group.

Currently if I pass the parrent, the child items automatically get passed in the SO that is created via restlet. Here unfortunately I can only control the Quantity and not price level.

Is there a way so that  I can pass( from different endpoint) Json to the restlet so that It can create the SO with all the right pricing for ItemGroup?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. You can't change the price of an item for a specific sales order. The price will only change if you change the value of the Item record in NetSuite.

You could look at adding discounts on your Sales Order. If your prices on an order differ from the item price on NetSuite,you can add a discount item to the sales order.